# What is the probability of throwing two dice and getting the sum of the fallen numbers greater than 3?

Tags: probability

Do you know how to calculate this probability?
The total number of possible outcome is $12$. Numbers that is greater than $3$ is $4,5,6$. For 2 dices that would be $6/12$ or $1/2$.

Is this a correct answer?

Comment: As alluded to in a comment of mine on another of your posts, you should be careful when using ratios of number of "good" outcomes divided by total number of outcomes *only* in situations where the outcomes are equally likely to occur.  The *eleven* possible sums of two fair six sided dice are *not* equally likely to occur.  (*The sum of $2$ only occurs with probability $\frac{1}{36}$ while the sum of $7$ occurs with probability $\frac{6}{36}=\frac{1}{6}$*).  Your sample space should be the 36 equally likely possible ordered pairs of numbers on the dice.

Answer (score 2):

Its easier to figure out the probability of getting sum less than $4$, which is only three cases out of $36$: $(1,1); (1,2); (2,1)$. Thus the probability of getting sum greater than three is $\large{1-\frac{3}{36}=\frac{11}{12}}$

Comment: Why do you use $1$ to minus the probability of getting the sum less than 4?

Comment: @JamesWarthington: we have two mutually exclusive cases: $A$) sum is less than four and $B$) the sum is grater than three. These two cases cover all possible outcomes, thus $P(A \ or \ B)=1=P(A)+P(B)$. You need to think about the number of outcomes when we throw two dice. There are 36 possible outcomes, 3 of them cover case $A$ and the remaining $36-3=33$ cases cover case $B$. So the probability of $B$ is a ratio of favorable outcomes to the number of all outcomes, $33/36=11/12$

Comment: Thank you, I understand it now.